# XML, DTD and related technology

Tags: xml, parsing, dtd

I am fresher and haven't much idea about the latest technology.

As i got some work on XML but i want to study more.

Can you please suggest me, What technology should i start study along with XML?

Comment: XML is almost 20 years old...

Comment: Maybe you could specify a little bit more what you're trying to achieve. It's not really clear what is being asked here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please go through first : http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_whatis.asp